# Android: Duplicating fragments in FragmentManager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, kotlin, fragmentmanager

**EDIT:** I want to solve problem of duplicating fragment in view Pager, removing them isn't the best solution.

I have a problem with `FragmentManager` in my app. Every time when I click "Wykłady teoretyczne" or "Wykłady popularnonaukowe" on Navigation Drawer my app is creating new fragment `ScheduleFragment()` which contains `ViewPager` and in `SchedulePagerAdapter` app is creating new 3 fragments (`ScheduleEventFragment()`) to swipe them in `ScheduleFragment`. My problem is that `FragmentManager` doesn't remove old `ScheduleEventFragments`, for all the time it keeps them in memory. How can I fix this problem?

I have my project on [GitHub](https://github.com/KamilZPWr/OMatKo/tree/schedule_fragment_genereted), please check it.

There you have screen from debuging [image: Debuging: Fragment Manager contains old fragments]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FragmentTransaction  fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.remove(R.id.container,fragment,optionalTag);
fragmentTransaction.commit();`You can also detach or replace

Answer (score 0):

Always check if fragmemt.isAdded() and then only add the fragment if not.